# Full Screen Fancybox on Mobile Allows User to Click Around

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, fancybox

I have a fullscreen fancybox where the user needs to input their date of birth in order to close the lightbox. However, on mobile, the user is able to tap the edges of the screen to get around the lightbox. This is most obvious when the user goes to enter the fields of the form (and the browser automatically zooms in) and then clicks the 'x' to get out of the form, they can then see the website behind the lightbox. See photo here http://postimg.org/image/n34gftg2x/

This happens on both chrome and safari on mobile.

The CSS for the outer div of the lightbox (not including Fancybox's included HTML) is:

```
#age-gate-cnt {
    height: 1000px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url('../../images/bg-hero3.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

The fancybox js settings are:

```
$.fancybox.open({
  content: '<div id="age-gate"></div>',
  closeBtn: false,
  modal: true,
  padding: 0,
  margin: 0,
  autoSize: false,
  fitToView: true,
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  scrolling: 'hidden',
  helpers: {
    overlay: {
      locked: true,
      closeClick: false
    }
  }, beforeShow: function() {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  }, afterClose: function() {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
  },
});
```

This site here: http://www.maestrodobel.com/ has a similar fancybox 'age-gate' yet it functions correctly on mobile.

Any idea what is causing this issue and how to prevent it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `position` to the containing element?

```
#age-gate {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This will then stick the container to the bottom of the page at all times.

You could also try adding `!important` if it's still struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any wrappers with `padding`, `margins` or `borders` in the fancybox default styling.

Also, your page is shrinking because it doesn't have an wrapper around telling that the position should be `fixed`, then it won't move. Apply the below to `fancybox-overlay`.

```
.fancybox-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

It should make the fancybox-overlay fixed, so it won't shrink or move when the window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: It seems the overlay div was not even appearing.

By adding the following code (empty function) to the fancybox js settings, I was able to solve the problem:

```
afterShow: function () {    
}
```

Comment: You should have tried removing the trial comma from your last option